# Use a class as a decorator

Tags: python-3.x

I am following the [:A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) to learn coroutine,

Here is a Task example from the instruction

```
class Task: #behave as a decorator
    taskid = 0

    def __init__(self, target):
        Task.taskid += 1
        self.tid = Task.taskid
        self.target = target
        self.sendval = None 

    def run(self):
        return self.target.send(self.sendval)

# a very simple generator
def foo():
    print("part 1")
    yield
    print("part")
    yield
```

Run it and come by

```
In [28]: t1.run()                                                                                                 
part 1

In [29]: t1.run()                                                                                                 
part 2
```

It is actually a decorator

```
taskid = 0 #set taskid as  a global variable
def Task(target, value):
    def enclosure(value):
        target.taskid += 1
        return target.send(value)
   return enclosure
```

just rename `.send` to `.run`

How could I call such an application to apply class as a closure,
Is it a formal jargon or pattern name for it?